# Is there a non-constant, real, continuous function $f$ satisfying $|f(x)-f(y)|\le\frac{|x-y|^2}{1+|x-y|}$?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, inequality, continuity

How to construct a real continuous function $f$ which is not a constant function satisfying the condition:

$$|f(x)-f(y)|\le\frac{|x-y|^2}{1+|x-y|}$$

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is not possible. You have the inequalities

$$|f(x)-f(y)|\le\frac{|x-y|^2}{1+|x-y|}\le \vert x-y\vert^2$$

And this implies for $x \neq y$

$$\frac{\vert f(x)-f(y)\vert}{\vert x-y\vert}\le \vert x-y\vert$$

Based on this inequality, you can prove that $f$ is everywhere differentiable with an always vanishing derivative. Hence $f$ is constant.

Comment: $|\lim_{x\to y}\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}|\le0\implies |f'(x)|=0$ Is this how it can be proved?

Comment: $\lim_{x\to y}\vert\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}\vert=0\implies |f'(x)|=0$ for all $x \in \mathbb R$ indeed.

Comment: This is nice, indeed you show that $f$ is „2-Hölder continuous“ and hence constant